# Instantiating Fragment from Activity via OnClickListner

Tags: button, android-activity, fragment, onclicklistener

Guys i am losing my mind, I want my Main activity to display the UI with the Button, once i click the button i want the Fragment to open, but i just cant seem to get it right, I know i have to create a ViewGroup Container so i can use the Transaction.add method but i have no idea what to do next or where to put it. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Main.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFragmentA);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.add(R.id.fragment1 , newFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dane.fragmenttest.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment A"
        android:id="@+id/btnFragmentA"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the fragment"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that you just need to do 2 things.

1. Add a container to your Main XML to hold FragmentA.

For instance:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dane.fragmenttest.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFragmentA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Fragment A" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. Update `onClickListener()` on MainActivity

For instance:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        FragmentA newFragment = new FragmentA();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container , newFragment)
            .commit();
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.